# C# Linq aggregate intermediate values

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, linq

Given an array of positive and negative numbers is there a Linq expression that can get intermediate values?

for example

```
var heights = new List<int>();    
var numbers = new [] { 5, 15, -5, -15 };    
var curHeight = 0;

foreach (var number in numbers)
{
    curHeight = curHeight + number;
    heights.add(curHeight);
}
```

This function will return `[5, 20, 15, 0]`

Aggregate can be used the same way and it would go through this sequence

```
numbers.aggregate((a, b) => a + b);
0 + 5 = 5, 5 + 15 = 20, 20 - 5 = 15, 15 - 15 = 0
```

My question is, is there a way to use aggregate or some other so that the intermediate values `[5, 20, 15, 0]` are returned?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you need is a custom version of aggregate:

```
public static IEnumerable<R> AggregateSequence<A, R>(
  this IEnumerable<A> items,
  Func<A, R, R> aggregator,
  R initial)
{
  // Error cases go here.
  R result = initial;
  foreach(A item in items)
  {
    result = aggregator(item, result);
    yield return result;
  }
}
```

That is a general mechanism for solving your specific problem:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> MovingSum(this IEnumerable<int> items)
{
  return items.AggregateSequence( (item, sum) => item + sum, 0 );
}
```

And now you can solve your problem with

```
mySequence.MovingSum().Max();
```

Answer (score 3):

With usage of `Aggregate`:

```
var result = numbers.Aggregate(new List<int>(), (a,b)=>
{
    a.Add(a.LastOrDefault()+b);
    return a;
});
```

result wil be:

```
[5,20,15,0]
```

If you want to have a Max value, you could use custom Result class:

```
public class Result
{
    public List<int> Values {get;set;}
    public int Max => Values.Max();
    public Result()
    {
        Values = new List<int>();
    }
}
```

use it:

```
var result = numbers.Aggregate(new Result(), (a,b)=>
{
    a.Values.Add(a.Values.LastOrDefault()+b);       
    return a;
});
```

and you will get the same List as `result.Values` and [20] as `result.Max`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this stuff within your aggregate function:

```
var intermidiateValues = new List<int>();
numbers.aggregate((intermidiateValue, next) => {
    intermidiateValues.Add(intermidiateValue);
    return intermidiateValue + next;
});
```

And then use

```
intermidiateValues.Max();
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with BAD perfomance:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var numbers = new[] { 5, 15, -5, -15 };

    var heights =  numbers.Select((o, i) => numbers.Take(i + 1).Sum()).ToList();
    foreach (var item in heights)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

It has O(n^2) complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own extension methods to do the accumulation/running totals with a custom projection and call it like:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
      var numbers = new[] { 5, 15, -5, -15 };

      // results 5, 20, 15, 0
      var results = numbers.Accumulate((a, b) => a + b);
      var max = results.Max(); // 20

      // providing a initial seed value: 20, 35, 30, 15:  
      var result2 = numbers.Accumulate(15, (a, b) => a + b);
      var max2 = result2.Max(); // 35
}
```

The extension methods:

```
public static class AccumulateExt
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> Accumulate<TSource>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TSource, TSource> funcAggregate)
    {
        return source.Accumulate(default(TSource), funcAggregate);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TAggregate> Accumulate<TSource, TAggregate>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        TAggregate initialValue,
        Func<TAggregate, TSource, TAggregate> funcAggregate)
    {

        return AccumulateImplementation(source, initialValue, funcAggregate, (_, agg) => agg);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TResult> Accumulate<TSource, TResult>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TSource, TSource> funcAggregate,
        Func<TSource, TSource, TResult> resultSelector)
    {

        return source.Accumulate(default(TSource), funcAggregate, resultSelector);

    }

    public static IEnumerable<TResult> Accumulate<TSource, TAggregate, TResult>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        TAggregate initialValue,
        Func<TAggregate, TSource, TAggregate> funcAggregate,
        Func<TSource, TAggregate, TResult> resultSelector)
    {
        return AccumulateImplementation(source, initialValue, funcAggregate, resultSelector);
    }


    private static IEnumerable<TResult> AccumulateImplementation<TSource, TAggregate, TResult>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        TAggregate initialValue,
        Func<TAggregate, TSource, TAggregate> funcAggregate,
        Func<TSource, TAggregate, TResult> resultSelector)
    {
        var last = initialValue;
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            var value = funcAggregate(last, item);
            last = value;
            yield return resultSelector(item, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: pfft @ericlippert beat me to the punch while I was typing it up =/

Answer (score -2):

the one line version

```
var numbers = new[] { 5, 15, -5, -15 };
var curHeight = 0;

int best = numbers.Select(x => { curHeight += x; return curHeight; }).Max();
```

as Eric has pointed out this is correctly stated a bad practice even though it works here would be a non destructive way of doing it

```
var numbers = new[] { 5, 15, -5, -15 };

int best = Enumerable.Range(1, numbers.Length + 1).Select(x => numbers.Take(x).Sum()).Max();
```

Comment: **Never do this**.  This is an **extremely bad programming practice**.  Select queries were not designed to be a replacement for loops that have side effects. If you need a loop then **write a loop**.  You can very easily get into situations where a query that "works" because of a mutation starts behaving extremely strangely when a minor modification is made to the query.

Comment: For example, suppose you refactored the code to `var q = numbers.Select(x => { curHeight += x; return curHeight; }); int best = q.Max();` Is that code still correct?  Great, it's still correct. Therefore `int best = q.Max(); int worst = q.Min();` should also be correct, right? But no, it is not. Queries that make mutations like this are little bombs waiting to go off in your code. Everything seems just fine, and then someone makes an *"obviously" perfectly safe* refactoring and everything suddenly blows up.  Just don't do it.